# Add style when when browser window width change

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am working on responsive wordpress theme and I have been creating an script that detect the `#header` height and add style to `.main_wrapper` of padding.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var header_height = jQuery("#header").height();
main_wrapper = jQuery(".main_wrapper");
main_wrapper.css('padding-top', header_height);
));
```

But the problem is when i open my site. It add a padding but when i resize my browser it didnot change the `.main_wrapper` padding

Comment: You haven't shared enough of your code for us to help you...

Comment: You don't have a `window.resize` handler, so your code only runs once, on pageload, it wouldn't run on window resize unless you told it to. This does sound like something you should try to find a CSS solution to.

Comment: media queries would benefit you greatly here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: Thanks All. I got my mistake. Did it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/94xw513j/1/

```
$(window).resize(function() {  
var header_height = jQuery("#header").height();
main_wrapper = jQuery(".main_wrapper");
main_wrapper.css('padding-top', header_height);
})
```